# Can I apply offset to continious anchor in jsplumb

Tags: anchor, offset, jsplumb

I want to use the "continuous" anchor placement option in jsplumb.
This works great, but the anchor is placed half inside the container div and half outside of the container.
I would like the anchors to be completely outside the container div.
If possible event with a small space between the div and the anchor (one or two pixels).

My purpose is to put those anchors on top of the arrows of the connections. I then want to make the anchors transparent so the user can "click on the arrows and drag". 
This is required because we are rebuilding an old java-based diagramming application. Our users are used to click and drag the arrows.

So can I offset the anchors so they will be x px outside the container div?

Thanks