# jsPlumb offset of a Continuous anchor

Tags: javascript, mootools, jsplumb

Two div elements which contain grids are linked using jsPlumb in such way that a specific row in one is joined with a specific row in another. For example gridA row 1 is 0.1 from top and is connected to gridB row 5 which is 0.9 from top.

[image]

I would like to pass only "y" variable to jsplumb anchor array but unable to do so and was able to pass "x" and "y" only in pair.

```
      var sl = parseInt(gridA.style.left.replace('px',''))
  var tl = parseInt(gridB.style.left.replace('px',''))
  if (sl<tl){
    var x1=1
    var x2=0}
  else{
    var x1=0
    var x2=1}
  var conn = jsPlumb.connect({
    ..... 
    ,anchor:"Continuous"
    ,anchors: [[ x1,offT],[ x2,offS]] 
 //offT,offS are calculated values 0.1 and 0.9 in the example
  })
```

The code has a problem that when div is dragged then values x1 and x2 from above stay fixed, for example gridA is dragged from one side of gridB to another. Connectors get wrapped around divs rather than linking on their adjacent sides.

This may be a related question: [Can I apply offset to continious anchor in jsplumb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20100798/can-i-apply-offset-to-continious-anchor-in-jsplumb)